# Change in migration behaviour between Django 1.7 & 1.8

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-1.8

I'm in the process of migrating an old Django app from Django 1.7. My current method is basically go to up a version then run manage.py test to see what I need to fix.

Something appears to have changed in Django 1.8 that breaks some of the existing migrations. The following worked in Django 1.7 but breaks under 1.8

```
def load_pilotranks(apps, schema_editor):
    PilotRank = apps.get_model('warbook', 'PilotRank')
    ranks = [
      { 'rank' : 'Champion', 'min_piloting' : 0, 'min_gunnery' : 0, 'skills_limit' : 0 }
    , { 'rank' : 'Star', 'promotion': 'Champion', 'min_piloting' : 0, 'min_gunnery' : 0, 'skills_limit' : 0 }
    , { 'rank' : 'Contender', 'min_gunnery' : 3, 'min_piloting': 4, 'skills_limit': 2, 'auto_train_cp': 1, 'promotion': 'Star' }
    , { 'rank' : 'Rookie', 'min_gunnery' : 4, 'min_piloting': 5, 'skills_limit': 1, 'auto_train_cp': 2, 'promotion': 'Contender' }
    ]

    for rank in ranks:
        if 'promotion' in rank:
            rank['promotion'] = PilotRank.objects.get(rank=rank['promotion'])
        PilotRank.objects.create(**rank)
```

Now this yields the error:
ValueError: Cannot assign "": "PilotRank.promotion" must be a "PilotRank" instance.

(While this example could probably be fixed by replacing the offending code with a JSON fixture, there are more complicated examples that would be harder to address).

The common denominator appears to be that the Model object returned by apps.get_model doesn't always work (if I use model.object.get() it will return an object that can be used to update that record, but cannot be used to set a reference to that object)

Whats changed that broke this?

Comment: At least this can be easily fixed with something like `rank['promotion_id'] = PilotRank.objects.get(rank=rank['promotion']).pk` (and `del rank['promotion']`), but weird find.

Comment: Is there a suitable equivalent for many-to-many fields (i.e. passing the ID to model.relation.add() ? )

Comment: I don't know if it works with the fake models you get in migrations, but normal many to many fields have a 'through' property that leads to the invisible background model; so model.relation.through.objects.create(object1_id=..., object2_id=...) could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I never figured out precisely what changed here, but in the end each case was solvable by manually using the ID fields in question instead, so for foreign key references `field = model` becomes `field_id = model.pk`

Many-to-Many references were a bit trickier, and were resolved by replacing:

```
model.manytomanyfield.add(match_mech)
```

With

```
model.manytomanyfield.create(model_id=model.pk, othermodel_id=othermodel.pk)
```

It's clunky, and a bit if a pain to do when you've got a few migrations to work through, but it gets everything running again and I've noticed no problems since.